# flatten an array of objects, while also considering for uniqueness

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following array of objects.

```
var array = [
{
    name: 'abc',
    place1: 'def'
},
{
    name: 'abc',
    place2: 'ghi'
}]
```

I am trying to get the following output

```
var array = [[name:'abc'],[place1:'def'],[place2:'ghi']]
```

this is my attempt:

```
let arr = []
array.forEach((element,index) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(element)
    keys.forEach(e => {
        let temp = [];
        temp[0] = e;
        temp[1] = element[e];
        if(!arr.indexOf(temp)
            arr.push(temp)
    });
});
```

but I am not getting the expected output.

Comment: The expected output is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how a an array of objects with different properties would help you. You should probably use one object with all properties or an array of entries.

However, to get the result you want - merge the array of objects to a single object by spreading into `Object.assign()` to remove duplicates. Then convert to an array of entries [key, value], and map back to an array of objects:

```js
const array = [{"name":"abc","place1":"def"},{"name":"abc","place2":"ghi"}]

const result = Object.entries(Object.assign({}, ...array))
  .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })) // remove the map to get an array of entries

console.log(result)
```